# i have a strange fear. can anyone help me?

Tags: fear

so ive had a **strange** fear of **dna** and I search what it is. nothing comes up and theres only why we get scared and its because of our **dna** but im scared of it and theres *"no such phobia"*

Comment: This site is for the construction of *fictional* worlds, your question does not fit here. If you feel so inclined, please take the [tour] and read up in the [help] about how we work. At present your question would not be suitable for any of the many sites on the network. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you had a basketball and you were somehow able to stuff three miles of monofilament fishing line inside the ball. That’s the analogy of the nucleus of every cell and how much DNA is inside it. And this little basketball nucleus is inside every cell in your body. Consider what a knotted mess that three mile long wad of fishing line is! Isn’t it amazing that the body has ways of copying it? RNA splits the double helix and makes a copy using special enzymes to “detangle” the massively long strand and untie the knots encountered in the process.

So what is it that you are afraid of? It’s microscopic so you’re essentially saying that you are afraid of chemistry. This chemistry goes on without your even thinking about it. In fact the only reason you are able to think at all is *because* of this chemistry. You needed to grow from an embryo to a foetus to a baby to a child to however old you were when you first learned about DNA. All that time, your nervous system was growing and maturing to the point when **pow** understanding happened. Before that time, DNA was working away, building the cells that make up you, whether you knew it or not.

Anyway your fear sounds like a manifestation of mysophobia or OCD. Get yourself some counseling and mention you’d like to be tested for OCD.

Comment: Thanks for actually providing a helpful answer. Yes the question is off-topic but if the question is genuine and not trolling it still deserves a proper response.